# windows features stuck on searching for required files

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, windows-authentication

I have a Windows 10 Pro Guest running on a Mac Host using Virtual Box.

For the Windows guest system, I want to activate Windows Authentication, so I went for `Turn Windows Features On/Off` --> `Internet Information Services` --> `World Wide Web Services` --> `Security` and checked `Windows Authentication`.

Now the system is stuck in `Searching for required files` for nearly half an hour! I already killed and restarted the process twice, the outcome was every time the same. It is confusing because on another, "real" Windows 10 (second PC) this worked like a charm.

[image]

Does someone know what's wrong here? I searched Google for solutions, without success. There are only forum posts with this problem regarding Net Framework 3.5 like [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/net-framework-35-installation-error-searching-for/721e950c-517e-45bb-a0cb-32474985c8d1) one.

I'm totally lost here. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

We understand your concern. However we would suggest you follow the steps mentioned below and check.

Search for `cmd` in search bar.

Right click on Command Prompt and select Run as administrator.

Copy paste the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
taskkill /im TiWorker.exe /f
net stop wuauserv /y
rmdir "%systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution\Download" /s /q
del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\qmgr*.dat" /s /f /q
cleanmgr /sageset:65535 & cleanmgr /sagerun:65535
​Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All
```

Then check if the issue still persists

Comment: This worked for me when trying to install IIS on Windows 10 and it was hung up.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that these same commands do not necessarily work in PowerShell, so it's important to use Command Prompt specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Running these commands can potentially cause issues or undesired effects on your system if not used correctly:

Interrupting Windows Updates: Stopping Windows Update services and deleting update-related files can disrupt the update process. This might lead to incomplete installations, failed updates, or difficulties in installing future updates.

Data Loss: Deleting files and folders within the Windows system directories (SoftwareDistribution\Download, qmgr*.dat, etc.) might remove important update files or configurations, potentially leading to system instability or update problems.

System Stability: Terminating essential processes (like TiWorker.exe) can impact system stability and performance. Although it's often used to resolve high CPU usage during updates, forcefully terminating processes can have unexpected consequences.

.NET Framework: Enabling or disabling Windows features like .NET Framework could affect applications and functionalities that rely on specific versions. Ensure you understand the implications before making changes.

Always create system backups before making significant changes to your system, especially when running commands that affect system files or services. These commands should ideally be used under the guidance of someone with technical expertise or after thorough research to understand their potential impacts.

Message H@CR...